# How to get substring in C++ and add character in between string

Tags: c++, string, substring, multiline

I have a string Hello foo how are you.

I want to change it to Hello\r\nfoo how are you.

I wanted to know the way to get the substring Hello add \r\n in place of space and add all other strings as they are. This is to show the multiline.

EDIT:

We don't know the length of first substring. We would not know how long the first substring will be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, because this looks like homework, but other approaches you could use include `std::find()` in `<algorithm>` and `strchr()` in `<string.h>`.  If you need to search for any whitespace and not just the `' '` character, you might use `std::find_first_of()` or `strcspn()`.

In the future, I’d check out the documentation for: the member functions of `std::basic_string`, the utility functions in `<string>`, the functions in `<algorithm>`, and the functions in `<string.h>`, as those will generally be the tools you have to work with.

Comment: I should add one addendum to that. You might often use the regular-expression library for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

To get a substring your answer lies with the function [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):

```
string::substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

1. **pos** parameter is the index of the first character to be copied as a substring.
2. **len** parameter is the number of characters to include in the substring starting from the index.

Returns a newly instantiated string object with its value being the substring from the specified string object it was invoked on.

```
// Example:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
  std::string str1= "Hello Stack Overflow";
  std::string str2 = str.substr (0,5); // "Hello
  std::cout << str2 << std::endl; // Prints "Hello"

  return 0;

}
```

---

### UPDATE: However it looks like different from your title, what you're needing for is to change some characters in between not knowing the substring's length

For that your answer is [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/):

```
string& replace (size_t pos,  size_t len,  const string& str);
```

Replaces the portion of the string that starts at index pos and goes up to index len.

1. **pos** parameter is the index of the first character to be replaced.
2. **len** parameter is the number of characters to be replaced starting from the index.
3. **str** string parameter to replace it with.

---

```
    // Example
    int main() 
       std::string str = "Hello Stack Overflow.";
       std::string str2 = "good";
       str.replace(6, 4, str2);   // str = "Hello goodStackOverflow"
       return 0;
    }
```

---

In some compilers you might not need to add it, but you will need to include the string header to make sure your code is portable and maintainable with:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: `string::substr` is used to get a sub-string not replace a sub-string, this is an inefficient answer, and quite frankly not what the OP asked for.

Comment: All you did was get the sub-string `"Hello"`, you never added a character in between the strings.

Comment: You still didn't answer the question, anymore and you're just copying my answer.

Comment: @chbchb55 We won't be able to find the answer as long as we do not know to what substring the asking person is referring to. As far as I'm aware I've let the reader know how to do two tasks that are in the title **with sources**. You are handing the exercise for the asking person in a platter, I'm giving him the tools he needs to do that.

Comment: He said `"I wanted to know the way to get the substring Hello add \r\n **in place of space** and add all other strings as they are."`

Comment: The sub-string the OP is asking for is clearly `" "`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s = "Hello foo how are you.";
  s.replace(s.find_first_of(" "),1,"\r\n");
  std::cout << s << std::endl; #OUTPUTS: "Hello
                               #          foo how are you."
  return 0;
}
```

What you want to use here is the [`string::replace(pos,len,insert_str);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/), this function allows you to replace a specified sub-string in `s` with your `"\r\n"`.

Edit: You want to use [`s.find_first_of(str)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) to find the first occurrence of the string `" "`

Comment: But for this I should know how many characters are there for the first substring. The scenario is we don't know the number of characters in the first substring.